# PHP – Find specific words in $_POST

Tags: php, post, sql-injection

I have made a login that is vulnerable for sql injections. Which is great. But I would like to avoid someone making use of DROP TABLE in the login. Can I, for example, somehow check if the input holds words like drop or table.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. But you shouldn't need to worry about that if you are using prepared statements and bound parameters. Show us what you have tried.

Comment: `"I have made a login that is vulnerable for sql injections. Which is great."` Do you mean to say, "Which is not great?". SQL injections isn't great, unless your Toby the Tiger, then everything is grrrrreat.

Comment: If you are going down this route you have to check for other SQL keywords. Hope nobody is called Grant.

Comment: This is the wrong way to approach the problem.

I should be able to use "DROP TABLE" as my username without killing your database.

Comment: @Layke, is Toby the Tiger a cousin of Tony the Tiger?

Comment: @Landon I was an under-privileged child, so we couldn't afford the brand names.

Comment: It’s not a login I am going to use I real life.
It is simply a test for the classmates so they know how to use sql injections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if (false !== stripos($_POST['username'], 'DROP'))` will work if you want to know if the word “DROP” has been mentioned in the “username” field posted.

Comment: @Jeff if the answer solved your issue, you have to pick it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use my simple, [PDO database library](https://github.com/Xeoncross/DByte) which will solve your SQL injection problems.

Read the code, it's not very long (~3kb) and it will teach you how you should be working with database queries using prepared statements. Then, later on you can move to real database library with features like migrations, query builders, and ORM implementations.

```
$pdo = new PDO(...)

$name = $_POST['name'];
// @todo make sure it's a good name

$statement = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `user` (`name`) VALUES (?)');
$statement->execute(array($name));

$user_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

### Update

Ok, so I just re-read you question and you actually *want* a SQL injection demo system - you just don't want it to be susceptible to *certain kinds* of SQL injects? This sounds like a bad idea that isn't worth the trouble. Setup a SQLite database which can be destroyed and re-created each page request and then you don't need to worry.

Comment: It’s not a login I am going to use I real life.
It is simply a test for the classmates so they know how to use sql injections.